# Problem while initializing attribute in constructor c++

Tags: c++, class, definition, construct, ctor-initializer

While i try to debug 
ERROR appear :
"Unhandled exception at 0x5784F2F6 (ucrtbased.dll) in Final project.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal."
Tried every thing can't figure out how to solve this.

```
using namespace std;
class Map :
{
private:
    double *mhours_played;
    string *maps;
    unsigned element_num;
public:
    Map() 
    {
         maps[2] = { "Summoner's rift", "Aram" };
         element_num = 2; mhours_played[2] = {};
    }

    ~Map() { delete[] maps; }
};
```

Comment: The fact that `maps[2] = { "Summoner's rift", "Aram" };` icompiles s an interesting coincidence. It doesn't do what you think it does. You can't assign to an entire array at once, the `= {a,b,c}` syntax only works when *initializing* it (and `maps` is not even an array). You probably want `maps = new string[2] = {"foo", "bar"};`, and similarly for `mhours_played`. And unless you're doing it for practice, you should be using `std::vector` instead of manually calling `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Does this work outside of a constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These statements

```
maps[2] = { "Summoner's rift", "Aram" };
mhours_played[2] = {};
```

do not make sense. maps and `mhours_played` are pointers that within the body of the constructor have indeterminate values. They are not arrays as you think. For example the expression `maps[2]`  is a scalar object of the type std::string.

Define the constructor at least like

```
Map() :  mhours_played( new double[2]() ), 
         maps( new std::string[2] { "Summoner's rift", "Aram" } ),
         element_num( 2 )
{
}
```

and the destructor like

```
~Map() 
{ 
    delete[] maps; 
    delete[] mhours_played;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the key misunderstanding here is the difference between stack and heap allocation. Your code would be (almost) correct if we were normally allocating space for an array in a function:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string maps[2] = {"Chad", "Zimbabwe"};
}
```

This is perfectly valid, and works as expected. However, what you're trying to do is dynamically allocate space for an array of strings in memory location `maps`. This syntax for this would be as follows:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string* maps;
    maps = new std::string[2];

    // ... more code ...

    // always free your memory!
    delete[] maps;
}
```

This tells the OS, "hey! I want some memory for an array, can I have some?" and the OS (hopefully) says "yeah, here you go have fun."

Currently, your code tries to access the second index in unallocated memory, and the OS *really* doesn't like that.

I hope this helps, and let me know if you need further clarification.